# Single Checkbox Form Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm working on a webpage where users can click a checkbox; any user can click the checkbox, and the result will be the same when viewed by all users. So, if User A checks the box, User B will see it as checked. If User B then unchecks it, User A will see it as unchecked.

I can get the checkbox to display the value from the database, but I can't seem to get the value to change and update in the database when a user clicks on the checkbox.

My blade layout looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('QuestionController@answered', $question->id) }}"  role="form">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <input type="checkbox" id="answered" name="answered" value="0" @if($question->answered == 1) checked @endif> Answered
</form>
```

The function in my controller looks like this:

```
public function answered(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $request->request->add(['answered_userid' => $this->userId]);
        $this->validate($request, [
             'answered' => 'required',
             'answered_userid' => 'required'

        ]);
        Question::find($id)->update($request->all());
    }
}
```

And, in my routes file, I have this:

```
Route::post('questions/answered', ['as' => 'questions.answered', 'uses' => 'QuestionController@answered']);
```

EDIT: I've updated it to include the name, but I'm still running into the same problem.

Comment: Checkbox has no `name` attribute and thus its value not gets sent.

Comment: @Miha_x64 I added that and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a name in the input. The request will use the `name` of the input as the parameter:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answered" id="answered" value="0" @if($question->answered == 1) checked @endif>
```

Comment: I added the name, but I get the same results.

Comment: It is going to be set when it is checked. When it is not checked, it will be not present in the request.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that, if the user select the checkbox, the request in the controller will have "answered" as a parameter with the value of the checkbox. If the user uncheck the checkbox, the request will not have "answered" as an element. Try both states and check if this is happening.

Comment: Nothing changes whether I'm attempting to uncheck or check the box.

Comment: Put a `dd($request->all());` as the first line of your controller method, check the box and send the form. Check if there is any value in the request.

Comment: Now I'm wondering, is the main problem that I'm having due to the fact that I'm relying on the checkbox itself to be what submits the form?

Comment: I would try a `<input type="submit" value="Submit">. Or it will never submit anything without javascript

Comment: Okay, I think that's what my problem actually was. I'm running into a different problem now, but it's one I can work with. I'll have to figure out how to have it submit with javascript later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the name and its value

```
<input type="checkbox" name='answered' {{$question->answred ==1 ? Value="1" checked : value="0"}}>
```